# Add List Of Images To HTML dynamic using c#

Tags: c#, html, dynamic

I have list of images stored in sql database.
i try to add it dynamic at run time .

i use `"InnerHtml"`
i create dive tag and want to add the image list in the div tag
**HTML:**

```
<div runat=server class="ws_images" id="List_Slide">
```

**C#**

```
List_Slide.InnerHtml = "<li><img src=data1/images/31.jpg alt=31 title=31 id=wows1_0/></li>"
```

can you help me ?

Comment: You'd like to populate the list of images dynamically, or you are generating static html, from the database? Because using jQuery for the gallery is good.

Comment: yes populate the list dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using ASP.NET web forms.

What you can do is drop a `asp:PlaceHolder` control onto your page then add Literal controls in there that contain your image HTML code.

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder id="ImagePlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
```

..
..

In code behind:

```
var literal = new LiteralControl("<li><img src=data1/images/31.jpg alt=31 title=31 id=wows1_0/></li>");
ImagePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(literal);
```

`PlaceHolder` does not render any HTML tags so if you want you can put your div tag inside the `LiteralControl`.